# TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'. on array.map()

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I understand that this TS error is essentially just a warning but I have been unable to find a solution when it occurs on `.map`

```
const files = require.context("./", true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key =>
    Vue.component(
        key
            .split("/")
            .pop()
            .split(".")[0],
        files(key).default
    )
);
```

I have tried checking if the value of `key` exists before doing anything else but it still produces the same error.

> TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of what `key` could contains ?

Comment: is it possible that `files` is not defined when the `.keys()` runs the first time but then gets hydrated later on? See if wrapping the `.map()` in an an if that checks if files is defined

Comment: can you try to do `files && files.keys()...` and see if the warning goes away?

Comment: The error is occuring within the `Vue.component()` on `key`

Comment: Have you looked at [any of the other questions that show up when searching on your error/warning](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TS2532%3A+Object+is+possibly+%27undefined%27)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to split a string. Using `someString.split("/")`, which does return an array. Using the method `pop()` does either return the last element of the array or undefined (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop))

Therefore your typing at that point is: `string | undefined` executing `.split(..)` on an undefined value will cause problems. That's what TypeScript is trying to tell you here.

To avoid this warning/error and to be type safe you could use the latest optional chaining feature TypeScript 3.7.0 provides you if applicable:

```
key.split("/").pop()?.split(".")[0] ?? someDefaultString
```

An alternative solution would be to extract this kind of logic into another function like so:

```
function extractValue(key: string): string { // you want to name that function better though
    return key.split("/").pop()?.split(".")[0] ?? "defaultValue";
}
```

And use it like:

```
Vue.component(extractValue(key), files(key).default)
```

Comment: The optional chaining seems to work in my console but VS Code is now giving me a `Expression expected.ts(1109)` where the `?` are.

Comment: That's probably because there is an issue with your TypeScript version. What TS version are you running?

Comment: I'm running ^3.7.3